# My function is not being recognized as a function, var is not defining my variable

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, math

I'm trying to make a simple calculator, but my function, calculate2() is not being recognized as a function.  It seems the variable, FleetSize, is not being defined properly as a variable using var.  Or I think it may be a scope issue.  But I can not figure out how to fix it.  I've tried and doubled checked everything.  Please help! Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="CNGSavingsCalculator">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">
                    <h1>CNG Savings Calculator</h1>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <th>
                    <h3>INPUT</h3>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h3>OUTPUT</h3>
                </th>    
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    Fleet Size: <input type="number" value="10" name="FleetSize" id="FleetSize" onchange="calculate2();"/> trucks<br>
                    Average  Miles Per Year: <input type="number" value="50000" name="Miles" id="Miles" onchange="calculate2();"> miles<br>
                    Average Diesel MPG: <input type="number" value="6" name="MPG" id="MPG" onchange="calculate2();"> MPG<br>
                    Diesel Cost: $<input type="number" value="4.5" name="DieselCost" id="DieselCost" onchange="calculate2();"><br>
                    Natural Gas Cost: $<input type="number" value="1.75" name="NaturalGasCost" id="NaturalGasCost" onchange="calculate2();"><br>
                    Incremental NG Truck Cost: $<input type="number" value="50000" name=IncrementalCost" id="IncrementalCost" onchange="calculate2();"><br>
                    Government Incentives: $<input type="number" value="32000" name="GovernmentIncentives" id="GovernmentIncentives" onchange="calculate2();"><br>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Natural Gas</th>
                            <th>Diesel</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="number" value="99224" name="GallonsNaturalGasUsed" id="GallonsNaturalGasUsed"><br>Gallons Equivalent Used</td>
                            <td><input type="number" value="83333" name="GallonsDieselUsed" id="GallonsDieselUsed"><br>Gallons Diesel Used</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>$<input type="number" value="183102" name="TotalAnnualNaturalGasCost" id="TotalAnnualNaturalGasCost"><br>Total Annual Fuel Cost</td>
                            <td>$<input type="number" value="375000" name="TotalAnnualDieselCost" id="TotalAnnualDieselCost"><br>Total Annual Fuel Cost</td>
                        </tr> 
                    </table><br>
                    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Results</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Payback on Incremental<br>Truck Cost: <input type="number" value="0.94" name="ROI" id="ROI"> Years</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Annual Fuel Savings<br>$<input type="number" value="191898" name="AnnualFuelSavings" id="AnnualFuelSavings"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate2() {
        var FleetSize = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.FleetSize.value,
        var Miles = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.Miles.value,
        var MPG = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.MPG.value,
        var DieselCost = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.DieselCost.value,
        var NaturalGasCost = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.NaturalGasCost.value,
        var IncrementalCost = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.IncrementalCost.value,
        var GovernmentIncentives = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.GovernmentIncentives.value,
            GallonsNaturalGasUsed = 10*FleetSize;
            GallonsDieselUsed = 20*Miles;
        document.CNGSavingsCalculator.GallonsNaturalGasUsed.value = GallonsNaturalGasUsed;
        document.CNGSavingsCalculator.GallonsDieselUsed.value = GallonsDieselUsed
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What's the error you are getting? If there is a problem with `FleetSize`, then that means that `calculate2` is recognised and called properly.

Comment: Learn to use your browser’s error console.

Comment: Do not use `document.CNGSavingsCalculator.FleetSize`! Either `document.forms.CNGSavingsCalculator.elements.FleetSize`, or much better `document.getElementById("FleetSize")`

Comment: Press F12 in the browser and go to the console to see the error message, should work in FF, IE, Chrome and probably others (to elaborate on CBroe's comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax. My code snippet shows how to declare variables:

```js
//Either this way:
var a = "something",
    b = 1,
    c = "another";

//Or this way:
var a = "something";
var b = 1;
var c = "antoher";
```

Mention the "," and ";" you are doing it wrong all the time. As far as I can see you are using it the other way around ;P

Your code cleaned up:

```
function calculate2() {
    var FleetSize = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.FleetSize.value,
        Miles = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.Miles.value,
        MPG = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.MPG.value,
        DieselCost = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.DieselCost.value,
        NaturalGasCost = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.NaturalGasCost.value,
        IncrementalCost = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.IncrementalCost.value,
        GovernmentIncentives = document.CNGSavingsCalculator.GovernmentIncentives.value,
        GallonsNaturalGasUsed = 10*FleetSize,
       GallonsDieselUsed = 20*Miles;
    document.CNGSavingsCalculator.GallonsNaturalGasUsed.value = GallonsNaturalGasUsed;
    document.CNGSavingsCalculator.GallonsDieselUsed.value = GallonsDieselUsed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `var` at the start of a statement to declare all the variables in it.

You can declare multiple variables at once by listing them after `var` with a comma.

You are putting `var` after a `,` (many, many times), which is an error.

Either get rid of the `var` (aside from the first one) or replace the `,`s with semi-colons to terminate the statement.

---

[JSHint](http://jshint.com/) is a useful debugging tool. It reports:

> 3 Unexpected 'var'.
> 3  Expected an identifier and instead saw 'var' (a
>   reserved word).
> 3  Missing semicolon.